# Customizing Devise recoverable validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I would like to customize the

> Reset password token can't be blank

validation error that happens if you submit users/password/edit without a reset_password_token as a query string parameter. This validation isn't in `devise.en.yml` and I can't find where the validator is declared in Devise's source. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reset password token error should just be a standard attribute `reset_password_token` with the key of `blank` that's stored in the model you are embedding Devise in. Assuming your class is called User and you're using ActiveRecord, this should work:

```
en:
    activerecord:
        attributes:
          user:
            reset_password_token: Password token
        errors:
            models:
                user:
                    attributes:
                        reset_password_token:
                            blank: was not found
```

Should give you "Password token was not found" as an error message instead.

Answer (score -2):

I pulled this out of the gem and put it in `config/locales`

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      not_found: "not found"
      already_confirmed: "was already confirmed"
      not_locked: "was not locked"

  devise:
    failure:
      unauthenticated: 'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.'
      unconfirmed: 'You have to confirm your account before continuing.'
      locked: 'Your account is locked.'
      invalid: 'Invalid email or password.'
      invalid_token: 'Invalid authentication token.'
      timeout: 'Your session expired, please sign in again to continue.'
      inactive: 'Your account was not activated yet.'
    sessions:
      signed_in: 'Signed in successfully.'
      signed_out: 'Signed out successfully.'
    passwords:
      send_instructions: 'You will receive an email with instructions about how to reset your password in a few minutes.'
      updated: 'Your password was changed successfully. You are now signed in.'
    confirmations:
      send_instructions: 'You will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes.'
      confirmed: 'Your account was successfully confirmed. You are now signed in.'
    registrations:
      signed_up: 'You have signed up successfully. If enabled, a confirmation was sent to your e-mail.'
      updated: 'You updated your account successfully.'
      destroyed: 'Bye! Your account was successfully cancelled. We hope to see you again soon.'
    unlocks:
      send_instructions: 'You will receive an email with instructions about how to unlock your account in a few minutes.'
      unlocked: 'Your account was successfully unlocked. You are now signed in.'
    mailer:
      confirmation_instructions:
        subject: 'Confirmation instructions'
      reset_password_instructions:
        subject: 'Reset password instructions'
      unlock_instructions:
        subject: 'Unlock Instructions'
```

Comment: Those are the generic errors in Devise for controller errors, not for model validations.